# How to display an array returned by a json object (foreach dojo)

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a json file returned as a json object (which is an array of arrays)...below is the returned json object

```
{
        "Info": {
        "Contact": "....  ",
        "title": "..."
            },
        "details": [
            {
                "ID": 1,
                "Question": "User ID",
                "Information": "",

            }, {
                "ID": 2,
                "Question": "Name",
                "Information": "",

            }, {
                "ID": 3,
                "Question": "Age",
                "Information": "",

            }
        ],
    "list": [
            {
                "No": 1,
                "response": ""
            }, {
                "No": 2,
                "response": ""
            }
        ]
}
```

Now i want to display only details...the below array

```
    "Details": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Question": "User ID",
            "Information": "",

        }, {
            "ID": 2,
            "Question": "Name",
            "Information": "",

        }, {
            "ID": 3,
            "Question": "Age",
            "Information": "",

        }
    ],
```

How do i do this?? please help..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) parse the JSON into a javascript object

```
var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

2) access the properties you want

```
var details = parsedJSON.details;
```

edit: You are parsing your javascript object back into JSON, why??

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6cFq/)

Comment: I tried this way..  Detail:function(DObject){

            var DAry = dojo.toJson(DObject);
            var D = DAry.details; console.log(D);   says UNDEFINED??/

Comment: @user1257271 your JSON is malformed, you have a bunch of extra commas (,) on the last property of each detail object.

Comment: @user1257271 see the edit in my answer. you should not be doing dojo.toJson

Comment: I am actually getting the json object from JSON file..here DObject is the json object..i want to display only details from that returned json object..i am new to dojo..i am somehow lost..

Answer (score 0):

```
var output = "";
for(var i=0; i<json.details.length; i++) {
  var detail = json.details[i];
  output += detail.ID +", "+ detail.Question +", "+ detail.Information +"\n";
}
alert(output);
```